# Why doesn't seaborn barplot retain the order of a groupby index?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, seaborn, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a seaborn barplot of a groupby object. Here is an example:

```
data = {'ID':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 
        'value':[10, 20, 30, 100, 200, 300], 
        'other': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e','f']
       }
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to use `groupby()` to group the data by `ID`, calculate the mean `value`, and sort in descending order by `value`:

```
grouped = data.groupby('ID').mean()
grouped = grouped.sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)
grouped
```

[image: groupby result]

Now I want to plot this using seaborn's barplot:

```
sns.barplot(x=grouped.index, y=grouped['value'])
```

This is the result:

[image: bar plot]

The plot retains the original order and ignores the fact that I reassigned `grouped` to change the order.

Why does this happen? I've tried so many different approaches, and it always yields the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always force the order:

```
sns.barplot(x=grouped.index, y=grouped['value'], order=grouped.index)
```

[image]

Comment: oh ffs. The answer was staring me in the face. Thanks @mozway! Do you have any insight into why I have to force the order in the first place when the object I'm passing to the function is already ordered that way?

Comment: I think if you have numeric data, seaborn tries to sort it automatically. See @BigBen's alternative that confirms that strings would behave differently.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can convert the ID to a string:

```
sns.barplot(x=grouped.index.astype(str), y=grouped['value'])
```

Output:

[image]